# iPhone location service - how to get data?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get location of iPhone that has location services on, when I don't know user login data without installing anything on device?

Answer (score 0):

No and Yes, You can use HTLM 5 location API in a website. But you will not be able to request iPhones location like with find your friend app.

Since you need to have your own backend to store to locations you will need have an app which will track the location and passes it to the backend.

Comment: Backend you mean sending somewhere?

Comment: Yes, all location data is only stored on the device.